# Window image stays for forever in the workspace after closing it

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, themes, workspaces

### The problem

I've installed the latest Kubuntu 16.04, installed the latest release of Kubuntu, making a fresh install.

Now, whenever a "secondary" window is closed, the image will stay forever.

What I mean by a secondary window is that primary windows like, Chromium, Firefox, Ktorrent, etc. Will close normally without secondary effects. However, windows like the "Files are missing" from Ktorrent (or selecting a file from chromium), will close but leaving its track. This "track" will appear when changing from virtual desktop to virtual desktop, but dissapearing after about half a second (probably what the transition occurs), while staying forever in the virtual desktop where it was originally closed.

### Example Images:

An example image is shown in the following image

[image: Screenshot]

An example taken just at the moment of a transition is as follows

[image: Cumulative]

### Notes

The images are cumulative, clicking on them has no effect (i.e. like clicking below the image, if the image is over a folder, it will normally open such a folder).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It has something to do with a bug when windows are set translucent. Go to system settings, desktop behavior, and then find anything that has a translucence setting and turn it off. Unfortunately thats an ongoing issue for now.

Hope that helps my friend.